# Would a Faraday cage made of gas block radiation?

Tags: mars, colonization, radiation, shielding

What is best blocks radiation and is transparent as a gas? Would applying an electrical current through the gas increase the gas from blocking radiation on Mars?

Radiation could be blocked by the mixture of $O_1 O_2 and O_3$. With the correct voltage to match the radiation frequency, and the presents of the EM field around the gas would it block radiation better?

I am using the balloon as a small scale example of a rubber bio-dome.

[image]

[Can air pressure be accumulated this way for a biodome or spacesuit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26429/can-air-pressure-be-accumulated-this-way-for-a-biodome)

Comment: Cosmic radiation down at the surface of Earth demonstrate how well gases block radiation.

Comment: Electric or magnetic fields do no affect neutrons, gamma radiation or other forms of radiation that don't have an electric charge

Comment: I don't see any relationship to Faraday cages here, except for the very general concept of using a protective outer shell to shield sensitive interior components.

Comment: @Muze There are online courses in space sciences. You could take several of them and it would give you a better framework to vet ideas against by explaining what the real problems are.

Comment: @Muze: the short answer is no. Gamma radiation is composed of high energy photons & a neutron can decay to a proton plus an electron plus an electron antineutrino

Comment: As a rule of thumb, radiation protection is proportional to mass

Comment: @Antzi  Even if the mass is increased with electrons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gas is mostly *not* matter, that's why you can move through gas so easily. This is why it blocks virtually no radiation. It's also why it does block electric currents; that needs a conductor. If you do try to send an electric current through a gas, you typically get an arc (lightning effect). This **produces** radiation.

And while gamma radiation is electro-magnetic, it does not carry an electric charge. That means it won't be repulsed by your electrical charge, nor will it be deflected by magnetic field lines.

Comment: is there anything that it would block?

Comment: A thick layer of lead will block gamma radiation. Other heavy metals may be used too. But shielding needs a lot of mass whatever material is used.

Comment: @Muze: A pile of Mars rocks would also work. As Uwe points out, the chief thing you need it mass. Gamma radiation is stopped by the nuclei of atoms, in the end (nuclear reactions are also their source, so that's not too weird)